# If %COMSPEC% is not set, how can my program find cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a windows application launched from a taskbar shortcut that has an environment in which `%COMSPEC%` is not set.

This later creates a problem for this application when it tries to create a window with a shell in it, and cannot find `cmd.exe`.

Does Microsoft recommend a method for finding `cmd.exe` apart from relying on `%COMSPEC%`? (If so, what is that method?)

If `%COMSPEC%` is not set, when or why or how often will `%systemroot%\system32\cmd.exe` also be wrong?

Comment: `cmd.exe` should (always) be on the PATH - and if not, uhm, yeah. Most programs simply launch `cmd` and let it resolve as-it-will.

Comment: If COMSPEC is not set, you can declare the system as misconfigured.

Comment: Assuming that you're dealing with your own machines (or machines belonging to the person who contracted you to write this code) and that fixing the underlying problem isn't an option, I'd go with calling GetWindowsDirectory() and appending `system32\cmd.exe`.  It doesn't need to work everywhere, after all, only on those particular machines.

Comment: I'm finding $COMSPEC not set within a Git bash script, on a Git instance installed with the experimental "no need for winpty" option. This seems to be [a more recent problem that affects other environment variables as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54188082/1048186).

Comment: As a hacky patch on a single machine, the expected value of COMSPEC is usually "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe." I hard-coded a system-wide environment variable to this value and it fixed my Git bash script.

Answer (score 0):

%COMSPEC% is set but not able to install the postgreSQL version on my system