# "cmd: command not found" from "start" command (open directory in Windows Explorer) in git bash?

Tags: git, shell, command-line

Why show the directory in explorer command does not work in git bash?

When I type simply

```
start
```

at the MINGW64 Cygwin prompt on Windows, it displays:

```
/usr/bin/start: line 8: cmd: command not found
```

Comment: I got a similar error, only missing the cmd in the output: `/usr/bin/start: line 8: : command not found`.  This was when I had checked the experimental "don't need to use winpty" feature when installing Git for Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though it shouldn't be necessary, try the following:

```
/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe //c 'start .'
```

`start` is a command that is *internal to `cmd.exe`*, so it must be invoked with `cmd /c` (and Git Bash apparently requires *doubling* `/` chars. to be recognized as `cmd`-style option-prefix characters).

However, there *is* a shell-script wrapper for it - `/usr/bin/start` - which does this for you.

In your case, this shell script unexpectedly complains about not finding `cmd`, even though `/c/WINDOWS/system32` should be in your `$PATH` environment variable by default - do check that variable and see if it's being modified unexpectedly somewhere.

`$PATH` is initially defined in `/etc/profile`, but can be overridden / modified in `~/.bash_profile`, for instance.

`/etc/profile` also contains helpful links in comments:

```
# Some resources...
# Customizing Your Shell: http://www.dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_5.html#SEC69
# Consistent BackSpace and Delete Configuration:
#   http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html
# The Linux Documentation Project: http://www.tldp.org/
# The Linux Cookbook: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/linuxcookbook/html/
# Greg's Wiki http://mywiki.wooledge.org/
```

Answer (score 1):

The git installer adds `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` to Window's PATH environment variable.

In some PC configurations, this may not be sufficient for all git execution commands to run. For example, I faced the situation where `git fetch` executed fine, but `git help fetch` produced the error `/usr/bin/start: line 8: cmd not found`

Following #mklement0's advice, after adding `C\Windows\System32` to Window's PATH environment variable, then all git commands executed for me without error.

Try appending `;C\Windows\System32` to your Window's PATH environment variable as follows:

- Open Windows Explorer, right-click on your Computer icon, and select 'Properies'. The System Control Panel opens.
  [Window Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ibQI.png)
- Select the 'Advanced system setting' link on the left panel. The System Properties window opens.
  [System Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avuJb.png)
- Select the 'Environment Variables...' button at the bottom of the window. The Environment Variables window opens.
  [System Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlCbA.png)
- The lower panel is the 'System variables' section. In this section, scroll down and select 'Path'. Then, click on the 'Edit...' button. A small window opens where you can edit the Path variable.
  [Path Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYgEG.png)
- While not forgetting the `;` add the following to the end of the 'Variable value' text: `;C:\Windows\System32`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem because my path had %SystemRoot%\system32 included.  It turns out that the env variable %SystemRoot% is not statically defined, but automatically included in the environment when starting cmd.exe or power shell.  Since MINGW64's bash is neither, it just saw %SystemRoot%/system32 and could not traverse that to find cmd.exe.

Changing path to use C:\Windows\System32 cured this.