# Getting an error when inputing "git config --help"

Tags: git

I was following along with the Code With Mosh git tutorial, and I inputted `git config --help` into git bash I got this:

`/usr/bin/start: line 8: : command not found`

What is going on? I should mention I have a Windows 10 OS. I am new to git.

Comment: What does running `git var GIT_PAGER` print?

Comment: Are you trying to run `git help --config`?

Comment: @VinitDivekar: `git <command> --help` in general does the same thing as `git help <command>`. In this case it should show the OP the documentation for `git config`, as run through his pager.

Comment: @torek ```git var GIT_PAGER``` prints "less"

Comment: @VinitDivekar when I print that I get a list of config settings, I want help on a specific commit

Comment: Hm, `less` should not be doing that in general, but see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44283733/1256452).  Also related: [How to change the browser for accessing git help pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44867986/1256452) It looks like your Git installation is set up to attempt to fire up a browser (perhaps even the deprecated Internet Explorer) when using `git help` and company here.

Comment: @torek, thanks. Wasn't aware. @dhruvRamaswamy, I would first check if the git is installed properly with  `git --version` command

Comment: @VinitDivekar the command prints out ```git version 2.35.3.windows.1```, is that the correct version?

Comment: @dhruvRamaswamy, git help command is used to get information about _git_ .What is that you are after in you specific commit?

Comment: @vinitDivekar I was trying to find help on the 'config' command